# C# SslCredentials и защита данных при использовании gRPC

Tags: c#, ssl, rpc, x509certificate, grpc

При использовании [gRPC](https://grpc.io) (новая технология от google, которая по своей сути является следующим витком развития REST) пытаюсь использовать root certificate + .pfx key (certificate chain) для защиты передаваемых данных. Приложение стоит на Windows Server 2012 R2.

Для защиты запроса используется объект **SslCredentials**, который состоит из:

- "string containing PEM encoded server root certificates" (1)
- и другого объекта "key certificate pair".

"key certificate pair" состоит из двух стрингов:

- "PEM encoded certificate chain" (2)
- "PEM encoded private key"(3)

Подробно в документации по [АПИ](https://grpc.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.SslCredentials.html).

**Проблема** в том, что после получения данных из хранилища сертификатов я собираю эти данные в **X509Chain**, но при попытке приведения к стрингу получаю какой-то дикий ексепшн:

**System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: "Процесс не обладает необходимой для выполнения данной операции привилегией "SeSecurityPrivilege"**

Получаю X509Certificate2Collection из хранилища :

```
private static string CertId = "CertId";
public static X509Certificate2Collection GetCertificate()
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My ,StoreLocation.LocalMachine); 
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, CertId, true);
            store.Close();
            return cert;
        }
```

Далее полученные сертификаты конвертируем в нужный нам PEM формат:

```
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = GetCertificate();
            var pfx = certCollection.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password");
            var cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (cert != null)
            {
                string pemCert = ExportToPEM(cert);//(1)
            }
            if (pfx != null)
            {
                string pemKey = ExportToPEMPrivateKey(pfx);
            }
```

Ну и финал:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = collection[0];

        X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();

        ch.Build(certificate);
        ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; //экспериментально 
        ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreWrongUsage; //экспериментально 

        string chaintString = ch.SerializeToString();
        /*System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: 
"Процесс не обладает необходимой для выполнения данной операции привилегией "SeSecurityPrivilege"."*/

        KeyCertificatePair key = new KeyCertificatePair(chaintString, PemKey);
        SslCredentials sslCred = new SslCredentials(PemCert, key);

        Channel _Channel = new Channel(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutantificationServer"],
            Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutentificationPort"]), sslCred); 
        client = new SignAPI.SignAPIClient(_Channel);
```

Пока пытаюсь сделать "просто, что бы работало", так что не судите строго. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Под каким юзером выполняется код? Приватный ключ помечен как экспортируемый в хранилище?

Comment: Данный код интегрирован в приложение ASP.NET WebForms. Выполняю в студии запущенной от админа, в дебаге, но как вы понимаете, приложение будет выполняться от iis_iusrs так как хостится на IIS -е. По правде сказать, не понимаю зачем мне вообще нужны какие-то пермишены на этом этапе, если мы уже все данные сняли и просто пытаемся выполнить приведение типов.... Не первый день борюсь с проблемой.

Comment: По сути "PEM encoded certificate chain" (2) - это private key + root certificate. Если кто-то подскажет как это должно выглядеть в итоге в PEM формате - я могу и не формировать объект X509Chain вовсе. На этом шаге у меня есть все необходимое и я могу составить Chain сразу в PEM формате через StringBuilder, но пока не могу найти как он должен выглядеть (какую должен иметь структуру)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь экспортировать приватный ключ, а это очень серьезная операция. Когда вы получаете сертификат из хранилища, приватный ключ не загружается в память (для безопасности). Вы можете использовать этот ключ косвенно, запрашивая цифровую подпись. Но что бы получить чистый приватный ключ, скорее всего для этого нужны привилегии.

Comment: @Zergatul Это не помогло. Моя тачка в домене и используя рекомендации из https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0112535c-9b2c-4f9b-96d6-85cff585b20b/the-process-does-not-possess-the-8216sesecurityprivilege8217-privilege-which-is-required-for?forum=sharepointadminlegacy и из https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn221953%28v%3dws.11%29 я предоставил права как доменному пользователю так и локальному, но ексепшн остался без изменений.